# UI with render world in window

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am trying to get something like this:

[image]

I want a UI windows and in the center of window I want to display my world.

I want to use scene2D and scene2D.ui with an Orthographic camera.

Any advice?

Edit: I know that I must use two stages in order get a ui and world windows but I don't know how I can tell to the world window stage that render its content in that section instead all screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about.

1. Use a [CustomViewPort](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#customviewport) for the stage responsible for rendering world. It is fairly easy to use and example is given in the wiki.
2. Let it be rendered on entire screen. This way you could keep UI backgroundless and space between components would be filled by world itself. It might be considered more immersive by many. You would also be allowed to use semi-transparent UI this way.

Anyways, it's a matter of taste.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I started with first approach that is what I wanted, but finally I am going to implement the second approach. But I have one question. When I click in ui from Scene2D.ui, the event doesn't stop and affect the world, How can I stop event when I click in a Scene2D.ui actor. I have implemented the input with `scene2dUIControl.addListener(new InputListener(){});`. I use `public boolean touchDown()` and return `true` but it doesn't work

Comment: You should look into InputMultiplexer class. For reference, use https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling